# apktool error libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file

Tags: aapt, apktool

I'm using a Linux machine to build Android applications and have run into this error while running this command.

```
apktool b GoogleCamera -o GC.apk
```

This is the error it out puts

```
W: /usr/bin/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libc++.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.androlib.AndrolibException: brut.common.BrutException: could not exec (exit code = 127): [/usr/bin/aapt, p, --min-sdk-version, 26, --target-sdk-version, 27, --version-code, 41362666, --version-name, 5.1.018.177470874, --no-version-vectors, -F, /tmp/APKTOOL5938966552810672173.tmp, -0, arsc, -0, META-INF/services/com.google.protobuf.GeneratedExtensionRegistryLoader, -0, apk, -0, bin, -0, arsc, -I, /root/.local/share/apktool/framework/1.apk, -S, /root/Downloads/GoogleCamera/res, -M, /root/Downloads/GoogleCamera/AndroidManifest.xml]
```

When I check aapt like this

```
cd /usr/bin
ldd aapt
```

It returns

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xb7f37000)
libc++.so => not found
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xb7e0b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb7e06000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7de7000)
libz.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0xb7dcc000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb7cd1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb7cb3000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7adf000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb7f39000)
```

Comment: libc++.so should come bundled with the build-tools

Comment: i already have it installed with its newest version:                                                                            Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
google-android-build-tools-installer is already the newest version (23.0.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 109 not upgraded.